# Table captions default to foreign language

Tags: tables, captions, babel, vietnamese

I am typing up a latex report for a Vietnamese client. In order to spell their name correctly, I need to import the relevant language package

```
\usepackage[vietnamese]{babel}
```

The only issue is, when I do this, it randomly changes the caption label of a table to local language! 'Bang' is the Vietnamese name for a table (I think).

[image]

Instead it should say:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={7.5in, 10in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage[tiny]{titlesec}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage[vietnamese=nohyphenation]{hyphsubst}
\usepackage[vietnamese]{babel}
```

Comment: Please extend your code to a full but minimal example that others can copy and test as is.

Comment: You'll probably need `\usepackage[vietnamese,english]{babel}` and then use `foreignlanguage{vietnamese}{xxx}` for words in non-English. So as your code sits here `\usepackage[vietnamese]{babel}` does what it is suppose to.

Comment: Do you even have Vietnamese text, apart from a name? If not, a Unicode-aware TeX engine (like `LuaLaTeX`) might be all that's needed, together with a font that contains the required glyphs.

Comment: @daleif. Amazing!! that has done the trick!! Thanks so much!!

Comment: actually, @daleif, do you have a link on your profile where I can send you a direct message? Might have a small project later this year where I will briefly need a latex expert (or do you have a peopleperhour.com account you can link?)

Comment: Sorry don't have time for those things

Answer (score 1):

For just a few words in Vietnamese (names, for instance) you don't need to load `babel`, but just the correct output encoding, namely T5.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T5,T1]{fontenc}

\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textvietnamese}{\fontencoding{T5}\selectfont}

\begin{document}

The program \texttt{pdftex} is an
idea of \textvietnamese{Hàn Thế Thành}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Be sure that when you copy-paste the name, combining accents are not used.

If you really need Vietnamese text, then `babel` is the solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[vietnamese=nohyphenation]{hyphsubst}
\usepackage[vietnamese,main=english]{babel}

\begin{document}

The program \texttt{pdftex} is an
idea of \foreignlanguage{vietnamese}{Hàn Thế Thành}

\end{document}
```